# if inside a switch case, to restrict cases

Tags: c++, c

thanks for the answers.

I would like to know if is it possible to restrict some cases of a swtich-case statement using conditional expressions. Like the code the follows.

```
switch(a)
{
    case 1:
    {
        do_1();
        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
        do_2();
        break;
    }

    if(condition)
    {
        case 3:
        {
            do_3();
            break;
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

Edited, sorry guys, I got the wrong condition, it's not related at all with the switched variable. Just another condition, external one. 
I just want to know if I can restrict the cases with an external conditions, otherwise, that cases inside the IF won't be analyzed if the condition is not satisfied.
Do I need the second break inside the if?

Comment: what would that condition be? I mean `a` is a number, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Move the conditional into the body of the `case`. Remember, `switch/case` is just a fancy `goto`.

Comment: What about *case condition:*?

Comment: Erm, that's what your `switch` statement *does*. You do whatever you need to do in each specific case.

Comment: This makes no sense. By giving a case, you're already giving a condition to be met. Case code will be executed iff that condition is met. Since equality is already covered, the only conditions left are comparisons . . . but if the case is 3, we already know everything about a and there's no point in comparing it to anything. It's like saying `if (a == condition && a == 3)`, which of course is nonsense. If `condition` is three, it's redundant, if it's anything else, the following block will be dead code. There's just no point to write something like that.

Comment: Of course, if the condition was checking something not directly related to the variable being switched on, that would be different. In that case, you would need to check the condition inside the case, as indicated in the answers.

Answer (score 11):

The short answer is no. You'd have to reverse the order:

```
case 3: 
    if (condition) 
        do_3();
    break;
```

Comment: The break has to go **outside** the `if`, otherwise it will fall through!

Comment: But this is silly ... it's already switched on `a`. `a` can *only* be `3` in that case.

Comment: @egrunin: good point (though as written, irrelevant, since `3` was the last case in the `switch`).

Comment: @BrianRoach: yes, so at that point, it's basically equivalent to `if (condition == 3)` -- which can still be meaningful.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Thanks for the heads up -- I've updated the answer to match the edited question.

Answer (score 4):

Either check the condition in each case:

```
switch(a) 
{ 
    case 1: 
    { 
        do_1(); 
        break; 
    } 

    case 2: 
    { 
        do_2(); 
        break; 
    } 

    case 3: 
    { 
        if (condition) 
            do_3(); 
        break;
    } 

    case 4: 
    { 
        if (condition) 
            do_4(); 
        break;
    } 
}
```

Or use a `default` block with a second `switch`:

```
switch(a) 
{ 
    case 1: 
    { 
        do_1(); 
        break; 
    } 

    case 2: 
    { 
        do_2(); 
        break; 
    } 

    default:
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            switch (a)
            {
                case 3: 
                { 
                    do_3(); 
                    break;
                } 

                case 4: 
                { 
                    do_4(); 
                    break;
                } 
            }
        }

        break; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you do this:

```
    case 3:
    {
        if (a == condition)
            do_3();
        break;
    }

    break;
```

Comment: But this is silly ... it's already switched on `a`. `a` can *only* be `3` in that case.

Answer (score 2):

The two ways that it can be done are:

1. Using pre-processor macros, assuming that your condition can be tested this way.

   ```
   #ifdef condition
       case 3:
       {

           do_3();
           break;
       }
   #endif
   ```
2. Move the `if` statement inside of the `case` block.

   ```
   case 3:
   {
       if (a == condition)
           do_3();
       break;
   }
   ```

Comment: I think that's the order you meant for the examples to go in. At least now people can read them.

Comment: "*What you wrote is invalid syntax.*" No, what he wrote is perfectly valid syntax. http://ideone.com/I4fy2

Comment: @Rob: Now that is very interesting. You should make an answer out of that (maybe explaining whether this is a GCC feature or something).

Comment: @Robᵩ you're right! To my surprise if I might add.. :).. The if never gets executed (though I see some asm generated for the if!).. would be nice for the compiler to at least warn (unreachable statement).. post updated..

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't support that.  But you could use function calls to split the switch into parts in order to reduce code duplication.  If you were trying to do something along these lines:

```
void func()
{
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            do_1();
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            do_2();
            break;
        }

        if(condition)
        {
            case 3:
            {
                do_3();
                break;
            }

            case 4:
            {
                do_3();
                break;
            }

            case 5:
            {
                do_3();
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You could split it up like this:

```
void func()
{
    if(!func_a(a) && condition)
        func_b(a);
}

bool func_a(a)
{
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            do_1();
            return 1;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            do_2();
            return 1;
        }

        default: return 0;
    }
}

void func_b(a)
{
    switch(a)
    {
        case 3:
        {
            do_3();
            break;
        }

        case 4:
        {
            do_3();
            break;
        }

        case 5:
        {
            do_3();
            break;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: C++ supports it.

Answer (score 0):

You will never be able to put an if condition there, as it doesn't work with C++ syntax.  You should move #3 outside of the case statement, or make it part of default case and check for the condition there.

Answer (score 0):

It compiles in C++. **But the result was unexpected to me**.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int test(int action, bool allow_restricted)
{
    int success = -1;
    switch(action)
    {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "Performing " << action << std::endl;
            success = 0;
        break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "Performing " << action << std::endl;
            success = 0;
        break;
        if(allow_restricted)
        {
            case 3:
                std::cout << "Performing restricted " << action << std::endl;
                success = 0;
            break;
            case 4:
                std::cout << "Performing restricted " << action << std::endl;
                success = 0;
            break;
        }
        default:
        break;
    }
    return success;
}

int main()
{
    test(1,false);
    test(3,false);
    test(3,true);
}
```

This is not the output we want.

```
Performing 1
Performing restricted 3
Performing restricted 3
```

It does not work as expected because the `switch-case` statement *jumps* instead of executing the `if` statement.

But in case of fall-through the `if` statement works(does not when `action == 3` and `allow_restricted == false`).

```
int test_fallthrough(int action, bool allow_restricted)
{
    int success = -1;
    switch(action)
    {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "fallthrough " << 1 << std::endl;
            success = 0;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "fallthrough " << 2 << std::endl;
            success = 0;
        if(allow_restricted)
        {
            case 3:
                std::cout << "fallthrough restricted " << 3 << std::endl;
                success = 0;
            case 4:
                std::cout << "fallthrough restricted " << 4 << std::endl;
                success = 0;
        }
        default:
        break;
    }
    return success;
}


int main()
{
    test_fallthrough(1,false);
    test_fallthrough(1,true);
}
```

Output.

```
fallthrough 1
fallthrough 2
fallthrough 1
fallthrough 2
fallthrough restricted 3
fallthrough restricted 4
```

With a `while` loop inside the switch, it gets more interesting.

```
void test_fun_fallthrough(int action, bool allow_restricted)
{
    bool initialize = false;
    switch(action)
    {
        do
        {
            case 1:
                std::cout << "Fun fallthrough, initializing " << 1 << std::endl;
                initialize = false;
            case 2:
                std::cout << "Fun fallthrough " << 2 << std::endl;
            if(allow_restricted)
            {
                case 3:
                    std::cout << "Fun fallthrough restricted " << 3 << std::endl;
                    if(3 == action)
                    {
                        initialize = true;
                        action = 1;
                    }
                case 4:
                    std::cout << "Fun fallthrough restricted " << 4 << std::endl;
            }
        } while(initialize);
        default:
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    test_fun_fallthrough(3,true);
    std::cout << "*********************" << std::endl;
    test_fun_fallthrough(3,false);
}
```

```
Fun fallthrough restricted 3
Fun fallthrough restricted 4
Fun fallthrough, initializing 1
Fun fallthrough 2
Fun fallthrough restricted 3
Fun fallthrough restricted 4
*********************
Fun fallthrough restricted 3
Fun fallthrough restricted 4
Fun fallthrough, initializing 1
Fun fallthrough 2
```

It is *unexpected* that we can jump to the restricted code even when `allow_restricted` is `false`.

Comment: No, it is not unexpected, it's standard and expected. Furthermore, this is not an answer to OP question. So is it possible, or not? and why?  Grab a fun read [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device).